# Help setting up sshfs

Tags: sshfs

I'm trying to sort out file sharing on my 16.04 PC and have been advised to use sshfs.

From the wiki I'm trying to follow the instructions but not getting very far.
I've installed sshfs and checked it is there but the 2nd instruction says to add myself to the fuse group using "sudo gpasswd -a $USER fuse"
However when I type that I get "gpasswd: group'fuse' does not exist in /etc/group"

As you can probably guess I am clueless when it comes to terminal and to be honest most things Ubuntu.

The wiki I am following is https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSHFS

Comment: Jakuje, I see we both edited my question at the same time getting rid of the auto corrects I didn't notice. Can you offer any advise please? I'm lost.

Answer (score 4):

As you are getting the following error message:

> gpasswd: group'fuse' does not exist in /etc/group

This indicates that there is no such group, yet!
Please test if there is and subsequently alleviate the problem as described below:

1a. check if there is a fuse group with:

```
    cat /etc/group | grep 'fuse'
```

1b. Or as :[Daniel persson](https://askubuntu.com/users/1676321/daniel-persson) suggested below:

```
    getent group fuse
```

2. If there is it would look like:

   ```
   fuse:x:1001:
   ```
3. If there isn't, add one like this:

   ```
   sudo groupadd fuse
   ```
4. At this point you can add yourself to the group with:

   ```
   sudo usermod -a -G fuse your_username
   ```

Comment: Welcome to [Ubuntu.se]!  **:-)** Could you please [edit] your answer and explain the why too?  Also please review my **[edits](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1163633/revisions)** and also review the [editing help](/editing-help) to improve the readability of your answers in the future... **;-)** After you've edited, leave a comment @Fabby and I'll come back and upvote if it's now a *good answer*...  **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby I was wondering how to make it look like like you did it, now I know!   I hope the ingress was what you where proposing. Being my first answer I hope this will do. ;-)

Comment: **+1**  *Now* it's a good answer!  **;-)**

Comment: you dont need `cat` to grep in a file, `grep` will gladly read the file:
`grep fuse /etc/group`
You should probably be using `getent` instead though, as groups might not always (or only) be stored in /etc/group:
`getent group fuse`
as a bonus, this will only search in the first field, and not match for example partial usernames